# ReactJS defaultProps empty function declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best practice defining a function `defaultProps` that is empty in ReactJS?

My solution so far is either **an empty arrow function** or **a null value**. Which way would be better?

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => {},
  onClickNull: null,
};
```

Comment: I think this depends on the situation whether "null" could mean something in your code. "null" means having no data, so if your code has a logic that handles differently whether `onClick` is defined or not, then `null` else use the null object pattern by declaring `() => {}`.

Comment: It's entirely up to you. If you want your code to know whether the function was provided, use `null` or `undefined` or leave the property off the defaults. If you don't need your code to know and want to be able to use it without any checks, use the no-op function. (I usually create a single no-op function I reuse, although with modern engines I guess there's really no good reason for that...)

Comment: The "no-op" term seems new to me. Thank you for your answer and the new dev term I gained @T.J.Crowder :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a right answer for this.

If you want to be more explicit in your code, go with the `null` and check if the function is `null` before calling it.

If you want to have less code, go with empty function.

The more important thing I would say, is to be consistent in the entire project.

Comment: My main concern was the possibility of performance issues using an empty function. However, your point of view helped me clarify it, thanks @Anas !!

Comment: How is having an empty function a performance issue?

Answer (score 5):

Important thing to keep in mind is that an empty function `()=>{}` is an object hence its truthy whereas `null` and `undefined` are falsy.

So if you want to check whether that event handler prop is passed on implementation and handle both cases (supplied and not supplied) differently, it makes more sense to go with `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: I faced this issue the other day, thanks for bringing it up!